# GoogleMap with ViewPager at bottom, ViewPagerFragment item scrollable in fullscreen

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement functionality like `GoogleMap` with full screen layout and `ViewPager` at the bottom.

Now `ViewPager` will be at bottom initially and user can scroll that vertically, if content of it are large in height. User should be able to do scroll in fullscreen (upto ViewPager's page item height from bottom to top as per in demo image below).

Currently I'm able to do achieve same UI effect with the help of `ScrollView`(with match_parnt height and its paddingTop like 380dp) inside ViewPager's fragment(layout code as given below).

Now Issue I'm facing right now is `GoogleMap` doesn't respond to any touch/click event due to `ViewPager` Fragment's `match_parent` height.

My expected result is `GoogleMap` must be able to listen touch/click events and ViewPager's Fragment must be scrollable vertically over the map from bottom to top direction.

I've found during search that we can use `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent` to make child view to listen for those touch/click events. But in my case ViewPager and ScrollView inside fragment are taking all touch/click events.

Piece of Code,

*activity.xml*

```
<FrameLayout
    ...
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <fragment 
        ...
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            ... />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            ...
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            ... />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

*viewpager_fragment_item.xml*

```
<ScrollView
    ...
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    ... >

    <LinearLayout
        ...
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="380dp" >

    <!-- 
            child views in here.
        -->
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

*Expected output demo*

[image: Expected output demo]

In this demo user can touch, zoom in/out on `Map`, can slide `ViewPager` and scroll ViewPager's Fragemt in full screen. So, this is what i'm trying to achieve for.

I would appreciate if anyone gives helpful link or some demo.

Please Help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Solved it using `BottomSheet` layout

Let me show you my piece of layout code to understand it fully.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    ...
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    ... >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <fragment xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            .... />

       <!-- Other layout component code like Toolbar-->

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            ...
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ... />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And in your java file you need to set peek height to bottomsheet layout.

```
    View bottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.bottomSheet);
    mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
    mBottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(300);
    mBottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(false);
    mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING);
```

I've made a demo is well you can find it [here.](https://github.com/JaydipZala/BottomSheet-Android)